# Spring Boot/Security Custom Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to solve for a couple of hours this ***simple*** issue.
Having read every blog/article that seem outdated, searching through stackoverflow too, i am not able to solve it.

In theory, when you want to use your custom Authentication provider, you create a class that implements
the **AuthenticiationProvider**

```
public class CustomAuthProvider implements AuthProvider {}
```

And implement the **authenticate** and **supports** methods.

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    return MyCustomAuthentication();
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (MyCustomAuthentication.class
            .isAssignableFrom(authentication));
}
```

And then create a SecurityConfig class that extends the **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** where you set your authentication provider.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider) {
      super(true);
      this.customAuthProvider = customAuthProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
    }
}
```

In theory, that should be it, that should work but yet it doesn't.
Using the debugger, i can see that the provider is registered in the ProviderManager and it is the only one, yet the **authenticate** method is never used.

What am i missing?

Comment: I'm guessing just the default `AuthenticationProvider` initiated by Spring itself gets injected. Can you verify this by putting a breakpoint on the line starts with `this.customAuthProvider...` and restart the application? Are you instantiating your `SecurityConfig` with `@Configuration`?

Comment: As i have answered in the answer below, yes i do use @Configuration and it is the correct CustomAuthProvider injected.  The problem is that the ProviderManager just ignores it when there is a need to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to put `@Configuration` on top of your `SecurityConfig`.

You might be injecting the default `AuthenticationProvider` initiated by Spring itself into your `customAuthProvider`. Make sure to initiate `CustomAuthProvider` and inject it into `customAuthProvider`:

```java
public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider) {
    super(true);
    this.customAuthProvider = new CustomAuthProvider();
}
```

Comment: I have already put the @Configuration annotation, and it is indeed the proper CustomAuthProvider injected so it must be something else which drives me insane.

Comment: Can you return just `true` from your `supports` method? Because it looks like you're comparing an authentication token class to an `AuthenticationProvider` class.

Comment: I have done that also, but it didn't change anything.
The provider is registered, but when the request comes i get an AuthenticationCredentialsException since the authenticated method is never used, so i can't find why the provider manager does not use the only provider it has.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may has the same problem with this one.
Without being completely sure, i believe that the provider was not being used because **i didn't use the username/password authentication/http headers.**
I wanted to access a token and work with the token, which means you have to use a filter before calling `authorizeRequests()` and `authenticated()`